# Parse Facebook Login Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to login to Facebook using Parse and create a new Parse user as result. There is no proper Facebook login Documentation for Parse. Some of them are really outdated I have browsed every Parse + Facebook login post on Stack Overflow and Could not get any answer.

PS I cannot comment on existing posts as I am just starting out on Stack overflow and my reputation is on the lower side.

I have the following code in a button. When I click on the button I am redirected to Facebook where I give permission and then it just stays there. Meanwhile in the console "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." is printed When I print out the user and error(**both are nill inside the PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground)**.

I have tried a lot of things like changing methods in App Delegate to find a work around for this. I have not succeeded until now.

The following is the code in my Button

```
         @IBAction func FacebookLogin(_ sender: Any) {

    //var permissions = [ "public_profile" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackground(withReadPermissions: permissions) { (user, error) in            if let user = user {
        if user.isNew {
            print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            print("User logged in through Facebook!")
        }
    } else {
        print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }    

}
```

Here is my app delegate relevant FB functions I added. It would be great if you could have a look at it

```
func application(application:UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication:String?,
        annotation:AnyObject) ->Bool{

        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)

    }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
    }


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
        // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = “xxxxxx"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = “xxxxxx"
            ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = “xxxxxx"
        })

        Parse.initialize(with: parseConfiguration)

        //PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()


        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook(applicationLaunchOptions: launchOptions)

        let defaultACL = PFACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.getPublicReadAccess = true

        PFACL.setDefault(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.background {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    }
```

Finally in my Bridging header

```
#ifndef ParseStarterProject_Bridging_Header_h
#define ParseStarterProject_Bridging_Header_h
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKcoreKit.h>
#endif /* ParseStarterProject_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Comment: can you show me your Info.plist in details ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your method:

```
func application(application:UIApplication,openURL url: NSURL,sourceApplication:String?,
        annotation:AnyObject) ->Bool
```

by this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Otherwise the SDK does not call your method

I hope my answer was helpful

Comment: Wow. That did it. Able to log in now. Thanks for all the help Julien.